# Select specific fields from linq query in list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to optimise my linq query, it looks like this:

```
List<List<Step>> steps = (from LoadTest l in monitoringTask.LoadTests
                     where (l.DateStart > (start - Core.session.timeSpanClientServer)
    && l.DateStart < (stop - Core.session.timeSpanClientServer))
                     orderby l.DateStart ascending
                     select (l.H_Scenario.Steps
                           .Where(x => x.IsActivInGlobalApdexCounting == true))
                           .ToList()).ToList();
```

And in order to optimise it I want to select only fields from class step that I need, so I created class `StepDTO`.

Here is class `Step`

```
 private class Step
        {
            private System.Int64 id;
            private System.Int32 responseTime;
            private H_Scenario h_Scenario;
            /other fields*/
        }
```

and class `StepDTO`

```
 private class StepDTO
        {
            private System.Int64 id;
            private System.Int32 responseTime;
            private H_Scenario h_Scenario;
        }
```

The question is how to get from a query `List<List<StepDTO>>` by creating a `StepDTO` instance in select clause instead of selecting whole `l.H_Scenario.Steps`.

Comment: kindly elaborate little bit more. i did not get your desire...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `Select` and create new object instance in it. Here you go:

```
List<List<Step>> steps = (from LoadTest l in monitoringTask.LoadTests
                     where (l.DateStart > (start - Core.session.timeSpanClientServer)
    && l.DateStart < (stop - Core.session.timeSpanClientServer))
                     orderby l.DateStart ascending
                     select (l.H_Scenario.Steps
                               .Where(x => x.IsActivInGlobalApdexCounting == true))
                               //Here is you creating your DTO
                               .Select(x => new StepDTO 
                                     {
                                           id = x.id
                                           responseTime = x.responseTime
                                           h_Scenario = x.h_Scenario
                                     })
                               .ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select (l.H_Scenario.Steps.Where(x => x.IsActivInGlobalApdexCounting == true)).Select(step => new StepDto { // assign values here}).ToList()
```